# How to notify caller about the status of the function called

Tags: c#, delegates, console-application

I have a task to resend emails to the clients whose initial mail have been failed for some reason, I stores all the information being sent in the email, even if the mail fails to send, that way I atleast have the data about what was send, and then based on that i can resend emails.

Now i have hundreds of such users, hence i have made a console application, which i will manually run. My application gathers all the Emails which has failed to send from EmailHistory table and generates a list of Ids via (function a), which is then passed to next function (function b), which loops through this list and pulls each email content and sends it.

My concern is, since (funciton a) simply generates the list and pass it on to the next function (function b) for the processing. Now (function a) has no updates as to how many emails has been send until now, so that it can be displayed on the console window via (function a).

Can anyone tell how the (function b) can send notification to (function a) about each mail been successfully sent, i need the count of the same to be notified to (function a).

```
namespace First
{
public class A
private void function a()
{
   // This function gathers all the Ids from EmailHistory table via a sql hit. 
}
}
}

namespace Second
{
public class B()
{
   public void function b()
   {
      // This is the function which gathers the Email Content (in the loop) based on the Id passed via function a()
        // After each successful loop completion this should pass the notification, which in turn is displayed on console window through function a();
   }
}
}
```

Comment: The normal tool for this is `IProgress<T>`/`Progress<T>`. If you want something simpler, just pass an `Action<T>`

Comment: @canton7 thanks for your update however can you please show some more details as to how shall i implement it.